# firebase forge is no longer allowing me to view the dataset

Tags: firebase

Has anyone seen this error message when accessing Forge:

Console Message:

```
failed: Error: too_big: The data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request.
```

Dislayed in Forge Viewer:

```
Data view could not be loaded: There is too much data in your Firebase.
```

This is happening accross all of my dev/uat/prod datasets.  These datasets in the exact same form.  Were fully and easily accessible across all levels.  This is not a big dataset.  The whole exported dataset is around 15meg.

Comment: We're seeing the same exact same data view error this morning. Contacted support@firebase.com and supposedly hear back within 4hrs. Rob @ Firebase is usually on the ball. We're on Bonfire Plan but only using <9MB data

Comment: I see the same problem. I can still see a subset of my data by drilling down in the URL, such as https://basic-fire-6307.firebaseio.com/status/dev/a14

Comment: Sorry about this, it was a temporary issue that is now resolved. Please give it another try.